# Jsonpath to show children with dynamic names

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have this json data that I was to parse with jsonpath:

```
{
  "kind": "tm:sys:hardware:hardwarestats",
  "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/sys/hardware?ver\u003d11.5.4",
  "entries": {
    "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/sys/hardware/platform": {
      "nestedStats": {
        "entries": {
          "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/sys/hardware/platform/0": {
            "nestedStats": {
              "entries": {
                "baseMac": {
                  "description": "00:00ยง:00:00:00:00"
                },
                "biosRev": {
                  "description": "OBJ-0065-xx Build: 1.06.043.0 05/02/2014"
                },
                "marketingName": {
                  "description": "BIG-IP VPR-C2400"
                },
                "pvaVersion": {
                  "description": "20"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see some parts consists of children named according to this:

https://[host]/path

I would like to be able to essentially ignore the host part by using a wildcard:

```
$.entries.https://*/mgmt/tm/sys/hardware/platform.nestedStats.entries.*.nestedStats.entries.marketingName.description
```

Note the wildcard replacing localhost (it differs depending on which host header is sent to the api endpoint).

I have no control over the server side. Any suggestion appreciated!

/Patrik

Comment: Please don't put important parts of your question on external systems like pastebin. Please also cut down the size of your question, including the JSON, to what is required to illustrate your problem. See http://www.sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the values of those baseMac, biosRev descriptions without filtering path, this should be enough

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String samplejson = "{\n" +
            "  \"kind\": \"tm:sys:hardware:hardwarestats\",\n" +
            "  \"selfLink\": \"https://localhost/mgmt/tm/sys/hardware?ver\\u003d11.5.4\",\n" +
            "  \"entries\": {\n" +
            "    \"https://localhost/mgmt/tm/sys/hardware/platform\": {\n" +
            "      \"nestedStats\": {\n" +
            "        \"entries\": {\n" +
            "          \"https://localhost/mgmt/tm/sys/hardware/platform/0\": {\n" +
            "            \"nestedStats\": {\n" +
            "              \"entries\": {\n" +
            "                \"baseMac\": {\n" +
            "                  \"description\": \"00:00ยง:00:00:00:00\"\n" +
            "                },\n" +
            "                \"biosRev\": {\n" +
            "                  \"description\": \"OBJ-0065-xx Build: 1.06.043.0 05/02/2014\"\n" +
            "                },\n" +
            "                \"marketingName\": {\n" +
            "                  \"description\": \"BIG-IP VPR-C2400\"\n" +
            "                },\n" +
            "                \"pvaVersion\": {\n" +
            "                  \"description\": \"20\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "              }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "          }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";

    Object baseMac = JsonPath.read(samplejson, "$.entries..nestedStats.entries.marketingName.description");
    System.out.println(baseMac.toString());
}
```

But, if you want to read those descriptions w.r.t only certain paths, like you want to read only `https://localhost/mgmt/tm/sys/hardware/platform/0` and NOT `https://localhost/mgmt/tm/sys/hardware/platform/**1**`, then solution should be something else.

Comment: Thank you! Sadly what I was after is to do it in the second way. I already went ahead and made a work-around (actually more or less the same as your answer) and I don't think there is a way to do it the way I initially wanted.